# iOS Enterprise Distribution name change

Tags: ios, certificate, enterprise

I've just renewed an iOS Enterprise certificate for a client and I've also created a new distribution profile against that certificate.

On the test devices there are apps installed that use the old certificate, which have also been trusted by the user, which is standard.  The apps still work as the old certificate hasn't expired yet.

So far so good.

When a new app (using the new certificate / profile) is installed it asks the user to trust the Developer again :-(

If I go to Settings->General->Profiles & Device Management there are now 2 entries under 'ENTERPRISE APP' both with, what seems to be the same name.  On closer inspection one says:

iPhone Distribution:MY COMPANY LTD/ (the old certificate, notice the trailing /)

and the other one is

iPhone Distribution:MY COMPANY LTD (but without the trailing /)

The App still works OK but it's very confusing to the end user.  Has anyone any ideas why the trailing / is now missing?  Is there a fix?  It's not the end of the world but I'd like to be able to clean this up, if I can.

Thanks for any help/advice you can give.

Regards

Steve

Comment: Update:  Once all the new apps are replaced with the new certificate the old entry under ENTERPRISE APP will disappear anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the name would have changed just from renewing the certificate - Apple probably just added some sort of filter to remove invalid characters, and that's why the / doesn't appear in the new one.

Unfortunately, there's probably nothing you can do about this.  The Company Name field on the certificate comes from the name you provided when you signed up for your developer account, and they don't provide a way to change that (at least not through the web site - maybe try a call to support?)

The other apps that use the old certificate will stop working once the old cert expires, so they'll need to be rebuilt with the new credentials anyway - the confusion will go away at that point, so at least it's not permanent.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks, that was my thinking as well.  It's no big deal but Apple certainly don't make it easy for us eh!